# 403 Error when trying to delete file's parent ( to move a file)

Tags: google-drive-api

In Drive, we have a use-case where we want to move a file -F1-  from a user's account - User X- to another user's folder - Fold1 - User Y.

These are the steps that we follow - 
i) Add User Y as an owner to F1 ( This request is sent as User X -- using X's credentials )
ii) Remove the current folder as the parent ( by sending a DELETE request to drive/v2/files/fileId/parents/originalFolderId) -- using Y's credentials

This is where I get a 403 - insufficient permissions for the file.

iii) If it gets beyond the previous step, we add the FOLD1 as a parent.

The above steps used to work up until last week.
Has the contract changed somewhere ? Can we not do it anymore ?

Appreciate the help on this.

EDIT: I tried the following also

i) add user Y as owner

ii) add fold 1 as parent ( so file will be in two folders)

iii) remove the original folder as the parent.

Still get 403, when trying to remove the parent in step iii).

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the original parent before changing the owner.

Comment: I get insufficient permissions when trying to remove the parent.
The request is made from the context of the original file owner. 
Is there a bug that was recently introduced ?

Comment: To clarify, are you still getting insufficient permissions *before* you change owner? Once you change owner the original owner may well have lost permission to do this change, which is why Cheryl is suggesting to do it as a first step.

Comment: Dan - For simplicities sake, let's say I basically have two contexts (access tokens) ... one for each user. 
To clarify my edit in the original question, I perform step iii) as the 'new owner' of the file (in this case user Y).. 
I should not expect a 403 file permissions error in that case, right ?

Comment: The new owner may not have access to the folder that the file was in. I'd have to test if that was actually a 403, but seems the likely culprit.  You could try it out in the API docs "try it" tool.

Comment: Cherly - Yes, the new owner doesn't have ownership on the original folder. But, I would imagine that not being needed...since, the new owner has ownership on the said file ?  
Also, my code ( and steps that I described), have been working fine for a couple months now. It suddenly stopped working or was it broken before ? Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Why is it a problem to remove it first?

Comment: So, I tried adding the new owner first and then, removing the original owner. It works but there seems to be a timing issue. 
In production, these two operations happen immediately after one another - here, I get a 403 exception. 

However, if I interleave these two calls by, say 2 seconds, it works. 
Do you know if it's a regression in Drive SDK ?